# Scrolling Delegate of tableView in Swift?

Tags: uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a question,In my `View Controller` i have dragged a `UIView` just above `tableViewCell` inside `tableView` which contains 3 `textFields`,above `tableView` i have taken a `collectionView` . My question is how that when i scroll the whole view controller to top i want to hide collection view as well as that which which contains those 3 textfields.And also create one new textfield and also position of tableview will be just below new textfield and when scroll the view controller down then that new textfield will hide and other things again show with same position as it is before scrolling.I have also tried  `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`but did not get it working Anyone help me with this.

Comment: Your question is very confusing for me. So can you explain

Comment: i resolved my issue bro @Gregory Wilson Pullyattu